# Rapetipeton — what does it mean?

Tags: vocabulaire, paroles-de-chanson

I’m listening to a song *J'habite une maison citrouille* by
Pierre Chêne where the lyrics goes

> J'habite une maison citrouille 
>   Rapetipeton le soleil est rond 
>   J'habite une maison citrouille 
>   Rapetipeton le soleil est rond 
>   J'aime les grenouilles
>   Et la pluie qui mouille 
>   Et l'omelette aux hannetons
>   Et l'omelette aux hannetons.
>
> [refrain] Tape du pied
>   Frappe des mains
>   Claque des doigts
>   Et clac, clac, clac

I’m a bit confused, what does *rapetipeton* mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lexicalement, ce n'est qu'une onomatopée dont la raison d'être est essentiellement rythmique.
Du même ordre que les *clac, clac, clac* du refrain ou ce que l'on trouverait dans *"Hickory Dickory Dock"*

Ces trucs sont très fréquents dans les comptines pour enfants car ils invitent à jouer sur des registres vocaux, à joindre de la gestuelle à la parole...

Peut-être, mais je ne saurais l'assurer, est-il un clin d’œil de Pierre Chêne à Pierre Desproges et sa "*Rapetipa*"... alors...

*si t'es fatigué, t'as qu'à prendre l'autobus!* ;-)

---

Edit suite à commentaire de Greg :

Le langage enfantin connaît *peton* pour dire *pied*. *petipeton* peut alors aussi évoquer chez l'enfant un petit pied... Cela vaut peut-être mieux quand on habite une citrouille... ;-)

---

Edit suite à suggestion de nonobstant fascisme :

Oui pour le peton de Pantagruel mais avec lequel, on sort du langage enfantin. Parce que... tant qu'à en sortir... allons-y :

*Strasbourg il est un pon garnison

...

Pon pon rapéti péton,

Rapéti péton, rapéti pompère,

Pon pon, rapéti péton,

Rapéti péton, rapéti pompom.* ;-)

Comment: *Rapetipeton* peut aussi évoquer *petit peton*, qui signifie "petit pied" en langage enfantin.

Comment: « Mon peton » ds. [Rabelais](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Pantagruel/%C3%89dition_Marty-Laveaux,_1868/Chapitre_3).